# Start new Activity on a button click

Tags: android, android-activity

I am very new to Android & Java and I know there are many questions and answer available on this site regarding starting a new activity on a button click. I read them and even I watched some videos on YouTube, but I don't know what am I doing wrong. I know it's very simple thing to you and hope you can help me out. Whenever I run I get an error as follows.

error: cannot find symbol class view
cannot find symbol class intent.
cannot find symbol class intent.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I am using Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.2

Following is Java code

```
package com.abc.xyz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.abc.xyz.R;

public class AddNew extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_new, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void goo(View view)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent (this, AddNewWeb.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Following is the xml layout code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.abc.xyz.AddNew"
    android:baselineAligned="false">    

<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="goo"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Is there anything that I should do in the other activity which I want to open?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you import android.view.View? Add this to your imports and are you in eclipse?

Comment: First, you should post the entire stack trace when dealing with errors of any kind.  Second, "cannot find symbol" generally means you are missing an import or library.  Here, you are missing an import for intent and view:  `import android.content.Intent;  import android.view.View;`.  Can you try adding that to see if it works?  Third, can you also post the contents of your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't import them. I am using Android Studio it used to show a light bulb when we have to import something but it's not showing now, did I change any settings?

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are missing all the imports here. Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to get all the imports, if you are using Eclipse.

Also, see to it that your Activity is registered in your XML file. It needs to be registered in the Manifest file for your app to be able to recognize your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this to your class:

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

Place it next to the other imports. That should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to import some libraries for example `import android.content.Intent;` now Why don't you try this?

```
public class AddNew extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
.
.
.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new);
    View btn = new (View)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
.
.
.
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
   if (v.getId == R.id.button2){
      Intent intent=new Intent (this, AddNewWeb.class);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to your problem. In fact, this is one thing which often slips out of your mind when you're dealing with new activities. In order to open a new activity, you need to add a permission statement in your AndroidManifest.xml file. Add the following line of code to your AndroidManifest.xml:-
     `<activity android:name="com.abc.xyz.AddNewWeb"></activity>`

Answer (score 0):

First clean your project from **Build==>Clean Project** and then
use this code in your onCreate() method

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_id);
button.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner)
{
   @override
   public OnClick(View v)
   {
      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContex(), YourActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
  }
}
```

Or simply implement **OnClickListner** and override the **OnClick** method and put this line in your **onCreate()**

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_id);
button.setOnClickListner(this);
```

if this code is not solves problem then check your JDK, if you are using JDK7 and project built at JDK8, so installe JDK8 and set path and java_home and run again, It's working fine....